# Mitubishi Outlander 2018. Replacing SIM card

Tags: mitsubishi, electronics, infotainment

Whatever I'm doing I'm not find the SIM card in my car. I removed the glove box (and see the white computer behind it. I removed the plasic below the glove box and still doens't find the SIM card, or a modem. There is anywhere else that it may be hidden there?

I'm sure that I have a SIM card, I just don't know where is it.

(Mitubishi outlander 2018 instyle) There is any more info that I can provide that let you better understand?

Comment: Are you certain you have one? How do you know?

Comment: Did you try the owner's manual?

Comment: Yes. I read the manual it is not written how. they want me to buy data plan from them

Comment: Please respond to the comment posted above by @RoryAlsop. Why do you think your vehicle has a removable SIM?

Comment: For serveral reasons. 1. In the MMCS about I see my IMEI and name of the celluar company (Cellcom). In the notification bar I see a sign of celluar signal (). My card dealer, told me that I have to pay $$$ for buy a new data plan, but because it was not activated for 2 years, I may have to come to change the SIM card to a new one. (I don't want his SIM card, I can get much better plans, I just don't know where the SIM card is hidden).

Comment: If it can help, I can open again the plastic below the glove box, and take a short video. Maybe someone with a sharp eye for mechanics can see it.

Comment: Both my wife's Honda Accord and my VW Jetta display the same symbols (including one for battery state of charge) when linked (either by Bluetooth or cable) to our cell phones.  These displays go away when the phone is disconnected. Thus,  I've always assumed that they show _the phone's connectivity_, not the car's.

Comment: *Who* wants to provide you with a new data plan? All you say is "the card dealer." If it was never activated, why do you need a new plan? The Mistsubishi page on [connectivity](https://www.mitsubishi-motors.co.uk/cars/outlander/connectivity) does not mention this option. It only talks about connecting to your phone by wifi or USB.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely location of the sim would be in the head unit itself.
Looking at the back of the head unit, there doesn't appear to be a sim slot.
They probably chose to hide it away so the end user can't replace it. At least, you can't replace it easily.

If you're handy with tools and not afraid of opening things up, I'd remove the head unit and open it up. If the sim card is in there you'll find it in a slot on the circuit board.